# Get DI from within class in Phalcon

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phalcon

How can I get the Service Locator (or the Dependency Object) from custom classes?

I have:

```
class CustomerHelper extends Phalcon\Tag
{

}
```

and need to get the `flash` service for use in a custom function

Comment: Instead of injecting the service locator, why not injecting directly the `flash` service?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: It's all in the documentation: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html

Answer (score 5):

You can always use this static method to get the DI in any class:

```
$di = Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
```

If you are extending Phalcon\Tag, there you can also use `$this->getDI()` or `self::getDI()` in a static context.

You can see more examples here: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html

Comment: Thanks. If I use `$di = Phalcon\DI::getDefault(); $messages = $di->get("flash")->getMessages();`, it works, however if I use `$this->getDI()` or `self::getDI()`, I get ` Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

Comment: Then you should add `Phalcon\Tag::setDI($di)`, when your application starts.

Answer (score 0):

Use Plugin as extended class

Example:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin, Phalcon\Tag;

class ClassName extends Plugin
{
    public function yourMethod()
    {
       $this->flash->error('msg');
       $this->flash->success('msg');
    }
}
```

Hope this fix your problem...